# Building a JavaScript grid from scratch

Tags: javascript, datagrid

I am curious to know what it takes to build a JavaScript grid from scratch. The grid should have features like jqGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html.

Can anyone please give me inputs?

Thanks

Comment: A whole lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

What it takes to build something similar to jqGrid:

- A huge, HUGE amount of time.

If something similar to what you want exists already, why would you want to spend lots and lots of time re-inventing the wheel? Anyhow, if you have nothing better to do, want to learn from it or if you are just curious, here is a list of skills that are needed to create a similar system:

1. HTML object manipulation.
2. Style manipulation.
3. Tons of different event handlers.
4. AJAX to grab (pages of) documents to display. Probably some server-side stuff too...
5. Creating of a nice layout system wich works in **every** browser.
6. Creating handlers to read and manage the different file types to support (XML, JSON, etc)
7. Creating HTML forms and reading them out with JS and then use AJAX to resave an XML, JSON, etc document back to the server.
8. An Algorithm to allow searching in the data you display.
9. Keyboard manipulation and the toggling off of standard key-events.

**10. Tons and TONS of debugging to make sure it looks nice in all browsers.**

Of course, this is only a tip of the iceberg since I don't really know the jqGrid program myself. I created this list by looking at some of the examples and reading the Features page.

Again, I would not recommend to rebuild such a big system from scratch, but the choice is of course yours ;).

Comment: I guess it would take around 6 to 8 months! Is that a fair thing to say?